# Regex to accept at least one alpha char and numeric char

Tags: javascript, regex

I was trying out a regex to "partial match" (any place in the string):

```
abcd1234 1a2b
```

I searched for a regex and found this:

```
/^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z])$/
```

But it accepts only alphanumeric; `abcd123!@#$` is not matched.

How can this be fixed?

Comment: atleast 1 alpha 1 numeric , but it  should also accept any other characters as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this?

```
/^.*[a-zA-Z].*\d.*|.*\d.*[a-zA-Z].*$/
```

This should match either:

- an *alphabetic* character somewhere, followed by a *numeric* character somewhere, with any number of other types of characters on either side or between them; **or**
- the other way around (*numeric* followed by *alphabetic*)

Comment: This fails if there's some non-alphanumeric character in between the letters and numbers, though (e.g. `abc@123`). Not entirely positive if that's in the OP's desired set, but it sounds like it is.

Comment: @eldarerathis: Good call. I *think* I've fixed that problem now.

Comment: yep that works thanks , if its no trouble for you , do you mind explaining it ?

Comment: `.*` matches any character 0 or more times. `[a-zA-z]` matches one alpha character. `\d` matches one digit. `|` is the OR operator. So everything to the left of the `|` matches OR everything to the right does.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, this is what you want:

```
/^.*[a-zA-z].*\d.*/

/*
'2344' => false
'abcd' => false
'a1cd' => true
'abc3' => true
'ab@3' => true
'a_*3' => true
'2_!b' => false
*/
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ZjDZy/2/ Yes but i was trying to use look ahead to avoid 1abcd as false

Answer (score 0):

The following will allow the alpha and the numeric to appear in either order:

`/^.*((\d.*[a-zA-Z])|([a-zA-Z].*\d)).*$/`